Every non zero element of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra is regular?
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $a \in \mathcal{A}$. We say $a$ is regular if there exists $b \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $a=aba$. It is clear that every invertible element of $\mathcal{A}$ is regular.

Is it true that every nonzero element of $A$ is regular?


No. Let $A = C[0, 1]$, $a = x$.

Thank you. That was so trivial.
